# How to save SVG files in Wordpress from an external plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a plugin for Wordpress in the administrative section to manage content, but I need to upload .SVG files but they are not being saved in the UPLOADS folder, I have tried many ways but none of them solves my problem:

Try this:

```
function custom_mtypes( $m ){
  $m['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
  $m['svgz'] = 'image/svg+xml';
  return $m;
}

add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'custom_mtypes' );
```

Try this:

```
function theme_name_mime_types($mimes) {
    $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    return $mimes;
}

add_filter('upload_mimes', 'theme_name_mime_types');
add_filter('mime_types',  'theme_name_mime_types');
```

and other options but without results, someone who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into similar issues before in that WordPress has changed the way that works in the code over time. So your solution may worked at some point, but is now out of date. Use a plugin like this https://wordpress.org/plugins/svg-support/ or https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-svg/ . That way if it changes again, you'll always be up to date with the correct way to do this.